# Best grow castle setup?

Tags: growcastle

I used this setup to grind from 300-600 and its pretty good. I would like to improve this setup but i just don't know what to put on the empty spots
[image: my setup]

I also want this to be good at wave clearing ( the evil horn thing ) and also good for grinding for gold